# How to call DAO without Factory?

Tags: java, design-patterns, mongodb, dao, morphia

As per my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049627/dao-and-dependency-injection-advice), I have the following DAO hierarchy:

**GenericDAO.java**

```
public interface GenericDAO<T, K> {
    public K insert(T object);
    public void remove(K objectId);
    // extensible
}
```

**GenericDAOMongoDBImpl.java**

```
public class GenericDAOMongoDBImpl<T, K> extends BasicDAO<T, K> implements GenericDAO<T, K> {
    public GenericDAOMongoDBImpl(Class<T> entityClass, Mongo mongo, Morphia morphia, String dbName) {
        super(entityClass, mongo, morphia, dbName);
    }

    public K insert(T object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void remove(K objectId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**ObjectDAO.java**

```
public interface ObjectDAO extends GenericDAO<Object, ObjectId> {
}
```

**ObjectDAOMongoDBImpl.java**

```
public class ObjectDAOMongoDBImpl extends GenericDAOMongoDBImpl<Object, ObjectId> implements ObjectDAO {
    public ObjectDAOMongoDBImpl(Class<Object> entityClass, Mongo mongo, Morphia morphia, String dbName) {
        super(entityClass, mongo, morphia, dbName);
    }
}
```

I'm confused on how I should go about using `ObjectDAO`? At this point in time, I think a *factory method* is overkill. So instead, it makes more sense to simply construct the DAO from the client like so:

```
ObjectDAOMongoDBImpl objectDAO = new ObjectDAOMongoDBImpl(clazz, mongo, morphia, dbName);
```

As `clazz` is dynamic, it might have proven a nightmare trying to alter the *factory method* to accept an argument, breaking my generic interface along the way.

Is there a cleaner way? I could have simply extended the *morphia* provided `BasicDAO<T, K>`, but this wouldn't have allowed me to easily change from *MongoDB* to *JDBC*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to look at Spring or Guice.  That's what we called Dependency Injection, so that "client" will not be responsible to perform lookup/instantiation for their dependencies.  These container will create the "beans" and inject the correct one you need in your "client" object, so that your client object do not need to worry about where to get the DAO, or which implementation it should use.

And in a DI world, it just doesn't harm to have different creation method for beans for different implementation.  These "dirty" things are centralized (e.g. in App Context config in case of Spring).

Comment: so you're saying my approach is fine (no _factory method_, I should just use something like _Guice_ instead of defining the concrete implementation class in my client code?